# Probability of three different tile types (each equally probable) not next to each other

Tags: probability, permutations

Helen has some black tiles, some white tiles, and some gray tiles. She places a single row of 8 tiles above her sink. Each tile she places is equally likely to be black, white or gray. Find the probability that there are no tiles of the same color next to each other.

What I did:

3  * 2  * 2  * 2  *  2 *  2 * 2  * 2

= 3*2^7

The answer should be (2/3)^7 = 0.0585. I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I would appreciate a detailed explanation starting from the very basics of the problem (i.e. the setup and then further on).

Comment: Your answer is the number of options. The probability is the official answer, and what you should do is take your answer and divide it by the size of the sample space, $3^8$.

Comment: so the size of the sample space is not *8!*?

Comment: No. Each tile has 3 color options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tiles are either Black (B), White (W), or Grey (G).

It doesn't matter what color the 1st tile is.
Without Loss of Generality, assume that the first tile is (B).

Let E be the event that a given tile does not match the previous tile's color.  Clearly, $p(E) = (2/3).$

In order to have 8 tiles in a row with no consecutive tiles the same color, the event E must occur 7 consecutive times, once for each of tiles 2 thru 8.

Hence the computation $[p(E)]^7 = (2/3)^7.$

I should point out that I made the simplifying assumption that there were (in effect) an infinite # of tiles to choose from.

That is, if you were to assume (for example)
that there were exactly 6 tiles of each color to start with, then once you (perhaps) ran low on a given color, that would effect the chance of event E occurring for the next tile.

Given that the provided answer is $(2/3)^7$, it seems clear that the simplifying assumption was made to ignore any possibility of one of the colors running low.

Note also that the constraint 
"Each tile she places is equally likely to be black, white or gray" 
may (also) be reasonably interpreted as meaning that you are to ignore any possibility of one of the colors running low.